# Modify dependency url before requirejs loads it

Tags: requirejs, amd

I'm using a JavaScript preprocessor on my code to generate modules for me but there's a problem, the url in my require method isn't the location that the files will be served from.

Assuming I can't modify the way the modules are generated how can I intercept the path going into require.js and modify the path so it looks in the right place? Essentially change `../../SomePath/app` to `/app`

My present solution is to wrap the require statement and modify it myself.

**Edit**

The `require` statement looks like this:

```
require(['require', 'exports', '../../SomePath/app/dependency.js'], function (require, exports, dependency) {
    //do stuff
});
```

So when I'm deploying the app my packager collapses `../../SomePath/app` to being `/app`.

Comment: Have you considered using `r.js` and killing two birds with one stone?

Comment: It's being packaged as an app so r.js seems like it'd add overhead that I don't need, also since the path that require.js thinks it's getting is wrong I'd expect r.js to have the same problem locating the file

Comment: Is this node or browser? If it's a browser, you might consider a `<base>` tag in your HTML file

Comment: Can you show the actual `require` statement? Sounds like the `paths` config should work - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that @Paul Grime was right, I can use the `paths` configuration, like so:

```
var require = {
    paths: {
        '../../SomePath/app': '/app'
    }
};
```